# Elasticsearch order aggregations bucket based on a field (can be text/string)

Tags: elasticsearch

My document has a category id.

This is my aggregation query:

```
"aggs": {
"categories": {
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_id",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        },
        "size": 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It produces the following results:

```
"categories" : {
  "doc_count" : 92485,
  "categories" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 4780,
    "buckets" : [ {
      "key" : 5053,
      "doc_count" : 21827
    }, {
      "key" : 5413,
      "doc_count" : 15760
    }, {
      "key" : 5057,
      "doc_count" : 12473
    }, {
      "key" : 77978,
      "doc_count" : 11388
    }, {
      "key" : 5030,
      "doc_count" : 9898
    }, {
      "key" : 5055,
      "doc_count" : 2492
    }, {
      "key" : 8543,
      "doc_count" : 2461
    }, {
      "key" : 5684,
      "doc_count" : 2106
    }, {
      "key" : 5050,
      "doc_count" : 2001
    }, {
      "key" : 8544,
      "doc_count" : 1803
    }, {
      "key" : 5049,
      "doc_count" : 1635
    }, {
      "key" : 5054,
      "doc_count" : 1284
    }, {
      "key" : 5035,
      "doc_count" : 977
    }, {
      "key" : 8731,
      "doc_count" : 817
    }, {
      "key" : 8732,
      "doc_count" : 783
    } ]
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the response such that buckets are ordered by category_id or any other field **post bucketing** as I want to select only 15 such buckets with maximum doc_count.

Also if possible is there a way do it based on a field which is text/string.

I tried sub-aggregation but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: To order by `category_id` simply order by `_key` instead of `_count`

Comment: @val I need to order by count first so as to retrieve the top 15 ("size": "15") buckets with max documents. And then I need to sort the buckets themselves based on a field.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example of how you'd like the buckets to be ordered based on a few sample documents?

Comment: You already would have what you are looking for when you sort using `category_id` as mentioned by @Val. Post sorting by `category_id`, if two buckets have the same count, the order of the categories displayed would be in lexicographical way if your `category_id` is string or it would happen `numerically` if its numeric. In short if two categories have same count, again ES would sort based on the default sort order of the `type` of your `bucket key`. Hope that is what you are looking to clarify!